# Member function pointer to unspecified class type - is it possible?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, c++03

Is it possible to declare a function pointer (non C++ 11) that can point to a member function of any class (read: not a specific class)?

For example, if I had class A, B, and C.  C has a function pointer declared in it, and I'd like to switch that pointer between pointing to one of B's member function's and one of A's member functions.  Does C++ allow this?

Comment: Function pointers can't be pointed at non-static member functions at all, you can only point pointer-to-members at non-static member functions and they have types specific the the member class and member type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::function` is able to do this together with `boost::bind`:

```
#incluce <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

struct A{ void f(); };
struct B{ void g(); };
struct C{
  boost::function<void()> _func;
};

int main(){
  A a; B b; C c;
  c.func = boost::bind(&A::f, &a);
  c.func();
  c.func = boost::bind(&B::g, &b);
  c.func();
}
```

Comment: Using type erasure and a layer of abstraction like `std::function` or `boost::function` uses essentially gives the poster what he wants.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, but you have to remove some type safety and keep track of the *this* pointer as well as the member function.

You can see a use-case in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11015/The-Impossibly-Fast-C-Delegates. The basic idea is to store the object pointer as a void pointer and redirect the function call through a static method.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A { void foo() { cout << "A::foo\n"; } };
struct B { void foo() { cout << "B::foo\n"; } };

class C
{
public:
    C() : object_ptr(0), stub_ptr(0) {}

    template <class T, void (T::*TMethod)()>
    static C from_method(T* object_ptr)
    {
        C d;
        d.object_ptr = object_ptr;
        d.stub_ptr = &method_stub<T, TMethod>;
        return d;
    }

    void operator()() const
    {
        return (*stub_ptr)(object_ptr);
    }

private:
    typedef void (*stub_type)(void* object_ptr);

    void* object_ptr;
    stub_type stub_ptr;

    template <class T, void (T::*TMethod)()>
    static void method_stub(void* object_ptr)
    {
        T* p = static_cast<T*>(object_ptr);
        return (p->*TMethod)();
    }
};

int main() 
{
    A a;
    B b;

    C c = C::from_method<A, &A::foo>(&a);

    c();

    c = C::from_method<B, &B::foo>(&b);

    c();

    return 0;
}
```

The code above should print

```
A::foo
B::foo
```

This solution is faster than using `std::function` since it doesn't require a heap allocated storage for the data but this may only be used to reference member functions (unlike `std::function` that claims ownership of any callable object).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. When you declare a member function of a class, that function has an implicit `this` parameter, so even though you write `void A::func(int i)`, the function actually has this signature:

```
void func(A *const this, int i)
```

You're going to need somethign like Boost.Function and Boost.Bind used together to do what you want to achieve:

```
boost::function<void (int)> func;
A* a = new A;
func = boost::bind(&A::func, a, _1);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could make A and B have a common base class X, and then you could use `T (X::*)(U...)` for both A and B (assuming the T and U are the same).

Or you could simply use `boost::variant`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

And it would not make sense if you could. Imagine for a moment that you could, and you have an object of type A and call a member function pointer that points to a member function of type B. Suddenly in a member function of B you would have a this pointer, pointing to the address of an A object, but having the type `B*`.

It depends on what the real problem is that you are trying to solve (maybe you should have asked about that) but you can try letting all classes have a common base function (maybe virtual) and use pointers to those, but unless you provide us with more detail, we could only guess.

Another, more broad, alternative could be to use `boost::function` objects, that are already tied to the object you want to call your member function on.